# Need to lazy load Angular Material library in Angular 8 project

Tags: angular, angular-material, lazy-loading

I want to use Angular Material's Drag and Drop feature in my app.

I don't want to initially load it, but only when I use drag and drop feature in a specific component.

I know how to lazy load modules in routes, but don't know how to lazy load a library.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how your project is structured. If your component is the only component in the related module then you can load the Drag & Drop module only for the component but if you have multiple components under the same module then you have to restructure and create a module for the component and import the Drag & Drop there.

```
import {DragDropModule} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop'; 
@NgModule({
  ...
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    DragDropModule,
    ...
  ],
  ...
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Maihan for the reply. Now I understood how we can do lazy loading of a 3rd party library.